# How to receive Octree?

Tags: ros, octomap, ros-kinetic, octree, avoid-obstacle

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am currently creating an Octomap through the [Octomap Server](https://github.com/OctoMap/octomap_mapping).
What I want to do next is to receive the octree for detecting obstacles while the octomap is being created.
I've tried this:

```
    octomap::OcTree* octree = NULL;
    serv_name = "/octomap_binary";
    
    while((nh_.ok() && !ros::service::call(serv_name, req, resp)) || resp.map.data.size()==0)
    {
        ROS_WARN("Request to %s failed; trying again...", nh_.resolveName(serv_name).c_str());
        usleep(1000000);
    }

    //Receive Octree
    msg_octree = octomap_msgs::msgToMap(resp.map);

    if (msg_octree)
        //Create object of type octomap::OcTree*
        octree = dynamic_cast<octomap::OcTree*>(msg_octree);
    if (octree)
    {
        ROS_INFO("%s: Octomap received %zu nodes, %f m of resolution", ros::this_node::getName().c_str(), octree->size(), octree->getResolution());
        tree_fcl = (new fcl::OcTree(std::shared_ptr<const octomap::OcTree>(octree)));
    } else
        ROS_ERROR("Error reading OcTree from stream");
```

Which works! This piece of code is inside a callback which loops with `ros::spinOnce()`. As this is the way it is done inside the octomap_server files, is it the best way for me to receive the Octree? Because while the vehicle is scanning the environment, the map keeps increasing, to the point where I am receiving more than 2 million nodes **at once!!!**.

Instead of updating the current Octree, I am receiving the whole Octree every time it loops through that code, right? My problem is that the code starts getting really slow. Is there a better way for me to receive the octree where I keep updating it instead of receiving all of it every time (with 2+ million nodes)?

Thank you in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/295539/how-to-receive-octree?/) by [jpde.lopes](https://answers.ros.org/users/34263/jpde.lopes/) on ROS Answers with karma: 64 on 2018-06-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found this [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/octomap/Px-FcbdE2_0) which answers my question.

---

Originally posted by [jpde.lopes](https://answers.ros.org/users/34263/jpde.lopes/) with karma: 64 on 2018-07-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0